# SQL Server joining temp table takes a very long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to add a column to the end of my results that shows if any item in a PO is stocked (with a 'Yes' or 'No'). opPOTRACK is my table with POs and other info that I want to display, inItemLocation is the table that has a row per item. They are (loosely) connection via opPOTRACK.cpono = inItemLocation.PONO after some text manipulation.

So far I've figured that the best way would be to put the results in a temporary table and then join that table with my normal query. Two of the tables join on a column where I have to derive the PO number (I didn't design the database and can't change the schema). Doing the string manipulation doesn't slow down my first join, so I'm not sure if it is affecting my second join. When I added the second join it just chugs for several minutes (canceled after 4 minutes; not sure how long it would really take).

I'm sure there is something messed up with how I'm joining.

---

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StockedTbl') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #StockedTbl
END

CREATE TABLE #StockedTbl
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PONo varchar(10),
    Stocked varchar(5)
)


INSERT INTO #StockedTbl
(
    PONo,
    Stocked
)
SELECT item.PONo, "Stocked" = CASE 
                      WHEN item.Loc LIKE 'ABC%' THEN 'No'
                      ELSE 'Yes'
                      END 
                      FROM inItemLocation item 

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_StockedTbl_UserID ON #StockedTbl(PONo)


SELECT  *
FROM  (SELECT  RIGHT(LEFT(item.PONo,6), 5) AS POTrunc, item.WhseLoc, po.cpono, po.Buyer, po.Vendno, po.OrderDate, po.StockDate, 
                      po.StockNote, po.Status, po.StatusChangeDate,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY po.cpono ORDER BY po.cpono) AS RowNumber,
                      st.Stocked
FROM          dbo.inItemLocation item
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.opPOTRACK po ON RIGHT(LEFT(item.PONo,6), 5) = po.cpono
                    LEFT JOIN #StockedTbl st ON RIGHT(LEFT(item.PONo,6), 5) = RIGHT(LEFT(st.PONo,6), 5)
) AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1 

DROP TABLE #StockedTbl
```

Comment: Can you try to create views that normalize your PONo values, and then join the views? I'm not sure the answer to why your current implementation has a problem, but I think if you had views do the manipulation of PONo and then joined the views it might work faster. Just a thought.

Comment: @Jim why? Unless a view is indexed it has to perform the same calculations at runtime as the normal query...

Comment: It would move the calculations out of the JOIN predicate, so the calculations would be done up front.  At least that's how I understand it; I could be wrong.

Comment: @Jim That may help, but using Aaron's answer below got me where I needed to be. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this instead. First, why does the `#temp` table need an `IDENTITY` column, and why does it need to be the `PRIMARY KEY`? Second, why not make a column that facilitates the join better?

```
CREATE TABLE #StockedTbl
(
    PONo varchar(10),
    Stocked varchar(5),
    PONoMatch AS CONVERT(CHAR(5), RIGHT(LEFT(PONo,6),5)) PERSISTED
);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON #StockedTbl(PONoMatch);
```

Now at least you can take those calculations out of some of your clauses, but depending on where the work is being done (the execution plan can tell us that), you may want to consider computed columns on your base tables as well.

Comment: OP said he "didn't design the database and can't change the schema".  So I assume that means he can't add a column.  That's why I suggested views in my comment, because maybe he's free to create a new set of views where he might not be allowed to alter the original tables.

Comment: The `IDENTITY` and `PRIMARY KEY` columns were (probably misguided) attempts to speed it up. After including the changes you suggested, it is now down to 9 seconds to run! Which is obviously a lot better, but is that still kind of slow for 2281 returned records? I think there are ~ 150k rows in the item table. I can live with 9 seconds if that's just how long it takes, but I don't want to cause undue burden on our SQL cluster because I'm not quite optimized.

Comment: Taking a look at the execution plan, it looks like costs are: ~25% from the `#StockedTbl` insert, ~50% from the `inItemLocation` Clustered Index Scan (25% from `#StockedTbl` insert and 25% from the join in my main `SELECT` statement).

Comment: @Jim the additional column on *the #temp table* I don't think qualifies as "can't change the schema."

Comment: @isorfir without knowing a lot more about the structure, indexes, stats etc. I'm not sure if 9 seconds is as good as you can get without making underlying changes to the data (if those 5 characters of that 10-character string are important, then you should be storing that separately). But what do I know? Maybe the views Jim is suggesting might make it 8.7 seconds.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks Aaron, I found what was taking the rest of my time: the CASE statement in the insert to my temp table. I found an alternative to using the CASE and now I'm down to 1 second.